# PHP Mustache Add CSS files dynamically

Tags: php, css, dynamic, mustache

I have a header template based on Mustache. I need to load CSS files dynamically.

This is how I load the header template:

```
 if(file_exists(_LANG_DIR_ . 'common.lang.php'))
            include(_LANG_DIR_ . 'common.lang.php');

        $header_tpl = $mustache->loadTemplate('inc/header');
        echo $header_tpl->render($common_page_lang);
```

`$common_page_lang` is an array from `common.lang.php`. The array looks like this:

```
$common_page_lang = array(
'css_files' => Link::GetInstance()->css_files, <-- this returns an array
'footer_loaded_text' => 'Footer Loaded!',
'site_title' => $dynamic_title,);
```

The css_files are list of an array containing all the required css for a page.

Is there any way of how I can load the css list from an array for the template?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{css_files}}" /> <-- this needs to be loaded as many as the $css_files array
    <title>{{site_title}}</title>
</head>

<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "implicit iterators" and it looks like this:

```
{{# css_files }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ . }}" />
{{/ css_files }}
```

That means, approximately, `foreach ($css_files as $.)`